# Run binary with ./ in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I decided to learn [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) (I program in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) at work), and I have been reading some tutorials (and lots of posts here on Stack Overflow). OK, so I typed in the standard C++ "hello word", compiled with [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) on my [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) machine as "test".

Then I tried to run it by typing "test" and hitting enter. Nothing. It turns out I must run it with "./test". OK, fine, I'll do that from now on. But why? The "./" just says that what I should run is in the current directory... Is the current directory not always part of the PATH when the [OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is searching for something to run? Can I make it so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the current directory is not part of your PATH.  You don't want it to be, because then you could be in a directory that had a malicious program you didn't know about that you run.

What if you were used to running /usr/bin/grep, but you happened to be in a directory that a Bad Person put a malicious copy of grep in, and this time you run grep, and you're running grep out of the current directory, rather than /usr/bin/grep.

You certainly can add ./ to your PATH in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile, but I don't recommend it.

And if it makes you feel any better, I had the same frustration 15 years ago when I started using Unix-like systems.

Comment: @Andy - may want to add that "test" is a normal *nix utility :)

Comment: @Andy, @warren - more important than "normal *nix utility", it's a shell built-in, which means that even if you put "." at the front of your path, it will use the build-in instead.

Comment: FWIW: traditionally multi-user systems (VMX, UNIX, Plan9) don't have '.' in the PATH, but single-user systems (CP/M and MS-DOS) do.

Answer (score 6):

You can add "." to your PATH, but that won't help you in this case - "test" is a shell built in.

Comment: Yes, I remember now. I have stepped in this trap before. So not only double but TRIPLE wtf on my part. Great.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is a Unix command called "test"...

Answer (score 1):

If there's a command line script you regularly run, you could set up a [command line alias](http://blog.geekblake.22web.net/2008/07/how-to-make-time-saving-command-line-aliases/) to rid yourself of the need to type ./ each time.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the current directory is at the very beginning of the $PATH, 'test' still won't run it on (most?) shells, as 'test' is a shell built-in command.

Answer (score 0):

Not having '.' (the current directory) in the PATH is a minor security measure. You could always add it in if you'd like, though it's not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's not clear, this is an aspect where Windows differs from Unix/Linux.  On Windows, the current directory is implicitly in the path.